# Run function after Meteor.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

In this instance, I'm trying to get a tick to open, `updateModel` on the screen when the user submits a form. I then want the `updateModel` to close. Once this is complete, if the form is open within a model I need the form model to close.

Getting the `updateModel` to open and close is working fine. This is the `Meteor.setTimeout` function. The problem I'm having is running the `if` statement afterwards. It runs before Meteor.setTimeout has finished running.

```
closeModel() {
  Meteor.setTimeout(() => this.setState({
    updatedModel: !this.state.updatedModel,
  }), 1500);

  if (this.props.addGuardianModal) {
    this.props.toggle(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `if` statement inside of the function given to `setTimeout` as well.

```
closeModel() {
  Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      updatedModel: !this.state.updatedModel
    });
    if (this.props.addGuardianModal) {
      this.props.toggle(false);
    }
  }, 1500);
}
```